# NOT FOUND (status code: 404): Unknown Message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently working on a Discord bot. I want the bot record all messages it sends on a specific channel. And if a specific text command is sent, I want the bot to delete all messages, then delete the one that the text command targeted and then send the messages again.

Current code:

```
import discord

current_queue = "current-queue"
current_queue_id = "454938696064696322"
join_channel = "join-queue"

queue_msgs = []
currently_queued_name = []
currently_queued_disc = []

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.author == client.user:
    if str(message.channel) == current_queue:
        queue_msgs.append(message)
if message.author != client.user:
    await printer(message)
    if str(message.channel) == join_channel:
        if message.content.startswith("!join"):
            await join(message)
        elif message.content.startswith("!leave"):
            await leave(message, queue_msgs)
        else:
            await client.delete_message(message)
async def join(message):
    await client.delete_message(message)
    currently_queued_name.append(message.author.name)
    currently_queued_disc.append(message.author.discriminator)
    await client.send_message(discord.Object(id=current_queue_id), message.author.mention)
    print("Manager has assigned {} to the queue.".format(message.author))

async def leave(message, queue_msgs):
    await client.delete_message(message)
    if message.author.name in currently_queued_name:
        for i in range(len(queue_msgs)):
            print(str(queue_msgs[i]))
            await client.delete_message(queue_msgs[i])
        queue_msgs = []
        print("Manager has deleted queue.")
        pos = currently_queued_name.index(message.author.name)
        del currently_queued_name[pos]
        del currently_queued_disc[pos]
        for i in range(len(currently_queued_name)):
            user = discord.utils.get(message.server.member, name="{}".format(currently_queued_name[i]), discriminator="{}".format(currently_queued_disc[i]))
            await client.send_message(discord.Object(id=current_queue_id), user.mention)
        print("Manager has updated queue.")
```

This works the first time I try to do `!join` followed by `!leave`. However if were to then do it again, `!join`, and then it would fail on `!leave` saying:

```
NOT FOUND (status code: 404): Unknown Message
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `async def leave(...)`, you have the following lines:

```
queue_msgs = []
print("Manager has deleted queue.")
```

In reality, `queue_msgs` hadn't been deleted yet, since you're just redefining the `queue_msgs` variable in the local scope. So the second time the function is ran, it tries to delete already-deleted messages. If you want to clear the `queue_msgs` by reference, change it to the following:

```
queue_msgs.clear()
print("Manager has deleted queue.")
```

When doing it this way, you don't even need to pass `queue_msgs` to the function, since it's already in the global scope. `async def leave(message):` should be sufficient.

---

Side note: you should be looking into the `discord.ext.commands` extensions, which helps you deal with the commands like `!join` and `!leave`.